# Access to the path is denied in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC program, I am trying to create a folder with name as UserID and I want to copy uploaded file to the location '~/Content/SickLeaveDocuments/'. But when I run program it showing error that 'Access to the path '***' is denied'.

Somebody please tell me how can I solve this problem.

```
string filePath = "~/Content/SickLeaveDocuments/" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                leaveDetails.SICK_L_UPLOAD_PATH = filePath + "/" + model.File.FileName;
                model.File.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath + "/" + model.File.FileName));
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                leaveDetails.SICK_L_UPLOAD_PATH = filePath + "/" + model.File.FileName;
                model.File.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath + "/" + model.File.FileName));
            }
```

I already checked file security permission settings and it has full control for the user. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Error is attached with it.
Thanks

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPCbf.png)

Comment: You need to `Server.MapPath(filePath)` before you're passing it to `Directory.CreateDirectory`

Comment: what about process permissions? If you run your c# app as administrator, does it still fail?

Comment: @haim770 My aim is to upload documents as separate for every user, so first I need to create directory for the user and to copy file to it.

Comment: @lorolabsKochi, Yes. But just like `File.SaveAs()` expects a *physical* path, so is `Directory.CreateDirectory()`. Your code is currently passing `filePath` (which is a relative path) as is.